# Intent for sharing image to Google Lens

Tags: android

I Want to share an image to Google lens app. so that it can analyse it and show result.

I have seen similar application in OnePlus Gallery App.

Comment: i'm not too sure if your question involves firebase, i could be wrong, could you perhaps add some more details if it does ?

Comment: Pretty sure it doesn't involve MLKit either.  I deleted the tag; feel free to re-add it with details if it was really applicable.